# Trunc(12.34) failing, do I need to reinstall RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently I'm only using the Shiny and Reticulate packages, but every time I try to use trunc(), even as simple as`trunc(12.34)`, I'm getting

`TypeError: trunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'`

I've already tried re-installing R. Has anybody seen this error before, or know what could be causing it? I'd like to troubleshoot and see if there's something else going on before reinstalling RStudio, as that becomes an ordeal with the IT department.

Comment: try `base::trunc(12.34)` Does this work?

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: Can you restart your R studio and try again

Comment: Alright, same error.

Comment: You then just have to reinstall R

Comment: what os system you have ?

Comment: Try R console not RStudio and run @onyambu solution `base::trunc(12.34)`

Comment: I have reinstalled R, my question is if I need to reinstall R-studio also. R I can do without admin control, RStudio I would have to get my IT department to do, which usually takes quite a while.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you try running `trunc(12.34)` on R (the Rgui one not Rstudio)

Comment: I forgot that R can be run in its own separate GUI(new to R, first project with it). That works, I'm assuming that means that there's something wrong with my RStudio, thanks for your help!

Comment: You likely have a local variable named `trunc`.  Run `getAnywhere("trunc")` to see where it is being found.  `rm(trunc)` would remove a copy from your global environment.

Comment: The only return for that command was ```package:base
  namespace:base```
I think it's fairly safe to say that my installation of RStudio is broken, given the multitude of issues I've been experiencing with it.